# Interpretation of $E((X-E(X))(Y-E(Y))^T)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, covariance

In the single dimensional case, it is the case that $E((X-E(X))(Y-E(Y)))$ corresponds to the covariance between X and Y. However, in the multidimensional setting, the covariance matrix of the multivariate random variable **W** is defined by $E((X-E(X))(X-E(X)^T))$.

I am therefore curious about whether or not there is an interpretation of $E((X-E(X))(E(Y-E(Y))^T)$, as this seems to be a multidimensional analogue of the covariance formula, however, this does not correspond to the covariance matrix of a random variable.

Is the resultant matrix used in any contexts, and if so what is its interpretation?

Comment: I think there is an extra $E$ in your title and later in the body of the question. $E(Y-E(Y))=0.$ I don't think you want the first $E$ there?

Comment: In any event, $$E((X-E(X))(Y-E(Y))^T))=E(XY^T)-E(E(X)Y^T)-E(XE(Y^T))+E(X)E(Y^T)=E(XY^T)-E(X)E(Y^T)$$

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the title @ThomasAndrews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am therefore curious about whether or not there is an interpretation of $\Bbb E((X-\Bbb E(X))(Y-\Bbb E(Y))^\intercal)$, as this seems to be a multidimensional analogue of the covariance formula, however, this does not correspond to the covariance matrix of a random variable.

This is called the **joint covariance matrix** for the random vectors. It is the matrix of covariances of members of each random vector.

$${[\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)]}_{i, j}=\mathsf{Cov}(X_i,Y_j)$$

(it is sometimes also referred to as the [cross-covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-covariance_matrix)).